# Recursion Pascal's Triangle (Python)

Tags: python, recursion, pascals-triangle

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with my code here in getting a recursive pascal's triangle to work in python. Any help is kindly appreciated :)

```
n = 5
def printPascal(n):
    Pascal_List = []
    if n == 0:
        Pascal_List.append([1])
        return Pascal_List
    if n == 1:
        Pascal_List.append([1])
        Pascal_List.append([1,1])
        return Pascal_List


    else:

        new_row = [1]
        final_r = printPascal(n - 1)
        last_row = final_r[-1]
        for k in range(1, last_row[-1]):
            new_row.append(final_r[k] + final_r[k - 1])

        new_row += last_row
        final_r.append(new_row)
        return final_r

print(printPascal(n))
```

Comment: You need to ask about a *specific* problem, rather than just say "Here's my code. It doesn't work. Please debug it for me". See [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made a few confusions in the loop that builds a new line. `range(1, last_row[-1])` doesn't really make sense; you want to iterate over the indices of the last row, ie `range(len(last_row))`. You've also mixed up `final_r` and `last_row` on the next line.

Here is a corrected version of your code :

```
n = 5

def printPascal(n):
    Pascal_List = []
    if n == 0:
        Pascal_List.append([1])
        return Pascal_List

    if n == 1:
        Pascal_List.append([1])
        Pascal_List.append([1,1])
        return Pascal_List

    else:
        new_row = [1]
        final_r = printPascal(n - 1)
        last_row = final_r[-1]
        for k in range(len(last_row)-1):
            new_row.append(last_row[k] + last_row[k + 1])
        new_row.append(1)

        final_r.append(new_row)
        return final_r

print(printPascal(n))
```

Comment: Thank you! You're a legend :D

Answer (score 1):

There is a better method to do this using the general formula for Pascal's triangle (n choose k), but I will not go into that.

Looking at your code, I'm guessing you are trying to add the previous two numbers from the previous row to get the next number.

Change replace with this in your `else` condition:

```
#It should be length instead.
for k in range(1, len(last_row)):
   new_row.append(last_row[k] + last_row[k - 1])
#You need to add the 1 at the end
new_row.append(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

[@zale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37207550/1639625) already explained the problem with your `for` loop, no need to repeat that. However, note that you can make your code a good deal simpler:

- no need for the special treatment of the `n == 1` case
- you can make the second part much simpler by padding the last line with zeros

Try this:

```
def printPascal(n):
    if n == 0:
        return [[1]]
    else:
        final_r = printPascal(n - 1)
        last = [0] + final_r[-1] + [0] # note: this does not modify final_r
        new_row = [last[k] + last[k - 1] for k in range(1, len(last))]
        return final_r + [new_row]
```